# Can a castling checkmate be engineered from this position?

Tags: checkmate, puzzles, castling, preparation, opening-traps

I get the following position pretty often in online bullet as White. It's mate in a few (for instance, 9. Bf4+ Kc5 10. Qd5+ Kb6 11.Qb5#). Needless to say, the setup is dubious.

This looks like a prime candidate for achieving ***castling with checkmate***. Black's king is running, their officers are passive, and many forcing lines exist.

```
[Title "Silly bullet trap"]
[fen ""]
[StartPly "16"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 exd4 { C44 Scotch Game } 4. Ng5? h6 5. Nxf7?? Kxf7 6. Bc4+ Ke8?? 7. Qh5+ Ke7 8. Qf7+ Kd6
```

Several ideas come to mind. For instance, it may be possible to open the d-file, mating by queenside casting. Or maybe the king may somehow be shepherded down to the a1 corner, with a kingside castling.

[image: short castle]  [image: long castle]

However, I cannot find concrete ways to do either. Can this be engineered? Sequences wherein checkmate by castling is merely one of several ways Black can choose to be mated are also be acceptable.

Comment: cann black help you in achiving this .faster the better, you dont want the king to hide on c7 or b7

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, it looks like it can at least not be forced. Black can chose to lose in the 9.Bf4+ Ne5 10.Qd5+ Ke7 11.Qxe5# line, and there's nothing white can do about it.

It is however possible to construct a full sound game tree where some of the nodes are castle mates, with all other nodes also leading to (regular) checkmates.

```
9.Bf4+
    Ne5 10.Qd5+ Ke7 11.Qxe5#
    Kc5 10.Qd5+
        Kb6 11.Qb5#
        Kb4 11.Nc3
            dxc3 12.bxc3+
                Kxc3 13.Bd2+
                    Kb2 14.Qd3
                        Kxa1 15.Bc3+ Kb1 16.O-O#
                        Nd4 15.Qc3#
                        Na5 15.Qc3#
                        (all others) 15.Qb3+ Kxa1 16.O-O#
                    Kxc2 14.Qd3+ Kb2 15.Qb3+ Kxa1 16.O-O#
                Ka3 13.Qb5
                    Qg5 14.Qb3#
                    (all others) 14.Bc1#
                Ka4 13.Qb5+ Ka3 Bc1#
            Bc5 12.a3+ Ka5 Qxc5+ b5 Qxb5#
            b5 12.Qxb5#
            (all others) 12.a3#
```

```
[Title "Desired result"]
[fen ""]
[StartPly "16"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 exd4 { C44 Scotch Game } 4. Ng5? h6 5. Nxf7?? Kxf7 6. Bc4+ Ke8?? 7. Qh5+ Ke7 8. Qf7+ Kd6 9. Bf4+ Kc5 10.Qd5+ Kb4 11. Nc3 dxc3 12. bxc3+ Kxc3 13. Bd2+ Kxc2 14. Qd3+ Kb2 15. Qb3+ Kxa1 16. O-O#
```